# Qual a diferença entre Observables e os eventos comuns do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eventos

Tenho visto muita gente falando sobre Observables e sobre o pattern Observer de um modo geral, principalmente da biblioteca Rx JS. Qual é a diferença entre Observers e os eventos que costumamos tratar, como `onclick`, `onkeypress`, `onkeydown`, etc? Se já temos a possibilidade de criar e responder a eventos, por quê precisamos de Observers "articifiais"? A função dos dois não seria a mesma?

Answer (score 1):

A diferença, principal, entre os dois é que um `Observer` serve para quando alguma coisa *muda*, ao passo que um `Event` ocorre quando alguma coisa *acontece*.

O exemplo prático disto seria, numa todo list:

A função que está aliada ao butão de "adicionar à lista" envia um evento a dizer "adiciona X à lista"; alguma coisa recebe esse evento e adiciona o X à lista; Quando essa lista muda, esta dispara um `Subscriber` para todos os `observers` com a informação necessária (normalmente, a nova data).

Ou seja: Um não substitui o outro e podem ser usados lado a lado.